# Estimating diffusion constant of a protein based on number of amino acids

Tags: proteins, amino-acids, protein-structure, chemical-communication

Is there a way to estimate the diffusion constant of a protein based on the number of amino acids it is comprised of. I know that the shape of the protein has an influence on the diffusion constant, but I didn't know if there was some estimate that could still be used to good approximation.

If this does not exist, is there still a way to approximate the diffusion constant of certain proteins. I am trying to make a rough model based on reaction-diffusion equations, and I wanted to estimate diffusion constants of certain species in the model.

Comment: Also, you can check PDB if the structure of the protein is available. If so you can get a reasonably close estimate of its shape *in vivo*. If not, then you can check out some software that predict protein structure based on homologous proteins. However, I cannot say that there is a good estimate of protein diffusivity just based on number of amino acids. Are you interested in a particular protein or you want to make a general model?

Comment: @WYSIWYG After further reading it looks like I am looking at a cytokine that only has about 25 amino acids (49.5 kDa). I am assuming this might be easier to estimate a diffusion constant for since it is so small?

Comment: @AaronStevens someone could have measured diffusivity of cytokines in blood and ECF (for [e.g.](https://www.jimmunol.org/content/198/1_Supplement/63.2)). If not, you can find the structure of a cytokine on PDB, obtain it's radius and estimate diffusivity using the [Stokes-Einstein equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory)).